# Extract value and add it in HTTP Request name

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to extract a value from one HTTP responseand add it in another HTTP Request name. It works, but when I run many threads, for example, 100 or more, the regex value is not displayed in the HTTP Request name. Instead it displays the default value. If the thread number is 100, then 10-15 are with the default value. what could be the reason?

[image]

[image: regex]

[image: Debug postprocessor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the server does not support 100 users load as it sending some other response (may by 5** HTTP response codes). save the results in `.csv/.jtl` file and check whether these error codes are observed.

If your script is working for a few users, but not working when load is increased, then it is the fault at server side where its resources might have touched the bottlenecks.

I suggest the following steps to try:

1. Increase the Heap space for JMeter (which is a Java application). default value is `512MB`. increase the value in `jmeter.bat`.

   set HEAP=-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
2. Run the JMeter in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) to save the resources.
3. while running the load testing using non-gui mode, specify `-l results.jtl` to save the results. once the test is completed, check for status codes under `responseCode` column.

Comment: I increased the Heap space. I checked the response code. It isn't throwing any error. The response codes are 200 but the name is still not extracted. But every time i run it, they are different records that don't extract the name.

Comment: Then, it is depends on server behaviour. If you are expecting different responses for the same request, then the regex obviously won't work.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way around. Is it possible to set the regex default value as the value that I get from the csv input? For the request that aren't getting the regex value, I can display the default value.if it is possible

Comment: You can use Default field in Regex Extractor

Comment: I tried giving the csv value in default field but it is not working. The csv inputs are 'name'. I gave the default value as ${name}.

Comment: what happened? Did it replace with `${name}` or `actual value of ${name}` when regex didn't work?

Comment: It just replaced with ${name } not the value of name when regex didn't work

Comment: there is additional space after name, please check. it must be `${name}`. I suggest using Debug sampler which shows the RegEx variable values that has been captured/assigned. You can use CSV value in `Default` field, it works.

Comment: It is ${name} without space in the test. It was a typo here. I will try using debug sampler and check.

Comment: I checked the debug postprocessor and I could see the correct value extracted in regex. But it is not applied to the HTTP request name. In regex extractor, I have selected 'Main sample and sub samples' in 'Aplpy to' and 'Body' in 'Field to check'. is that correct? Also the default value which is the csv value is not working

Comment: if value is captured using Regex, then `Default` won't be used. please add the screenshot of the regex extractor. also Debug sampler screenshot in View Results Tree

Comment: added the screenshots

Comment: Ok. as the `Hotel_name` is captured, it won't use `default` value. what is sent when you used `${Hotel_name}`. pls add screenshot

Comment: I just made a mistake. I didn't notice the regex that is in the HTTP request while loop and it was referring to it and that's why I wasn't getting desired results. Sorry for this confusion and thanks a lot for helping me debug.